# What did I wrong on importing a custom font?

Tags: java, fonts

So I want to use the ocr-a font for my Text in my little Brick Breaker Game.

I tried to import a font I downloaded as .ttf. Then I tried to use it on my JButton with "btn_StartGame.setFont(ocr);". But then when I try to run it the Font didn't change. Can somebody please help me. I'm still learning to code so if I can do something better just tell me.

This should only be something like a starting window and a game window where the actual game runs which is not created yet.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BrickBreaker extends JFrame
{
    Font ocr;
    
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_StartGame;
    
    public BrickBreaker()
    {
        components();
    }
    
    private void components() 
    {
        try
        {
            ocr = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("ocr-aregular.ttf")).deriveFont(100f);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(ocr);
        } catch(IOException | FontFormatException e)
        {
            
        }
        
        JFrame menuFrame = new JFrame();
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
        
        ImageIcon frameIcon = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Programmieren/Java/Brick Breaker/BrickBreakerLogo.png");
        
        menuFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(menuFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        menuFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        menuFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        menuFrame.setTitle("Menu");
        menuFrame.setIconImage(frameIcon.getImage());
        menuFrame.setResizable(false);
        menuFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);
        menuFrame.pack();
        menuFrame.setVisible(true);
        
        gameFrame.setIconImage(frameIcon.getImage());
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(gameFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gameFrame.setTitle("Brick Breaker");
        gameFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        gameFrame.setResizable(false);
        gameFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.gray);
        gameFrame.pack();
        gameFrame.setVisible(false);
        
        btn_StartGame = new JButton();
        btn_StartGame.setText("Start Game");
        btn_StartGame.setFont(ocr);
        btn_StartGame.setBounds(250, 400, 300, 100);
        btn_StartGame.setBackground(Color.black);
        
        btn_StartGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                menuFrame.setVisible(false);
                gameFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        menuFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        menuFrame.getContentPane().add(btn_StartGame);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new BrickBreaker().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting errors you are catching some but not doing anything with them, How would you know if something was wrong?

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack Im not getting any errors. If you see some then tell me please.

Comment: Don't ignore the exceptions in the catch block.  At a minimum you should do `e.printStackTrace();`  And it's considered bad practice to extend `JFrame`.  Just use an instance.